# Writing not permitted on genuino 101 Built in Bluetooth LE (phonegap)

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Genuino 101 which has a built in Bluetooth LE module. I have been trying to connect this to my phone using phonegap. I have been using [cordova-plugin-bluetootle](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) and with it I have been able to receive data from the arduino and display that data on the phone.
I tired adapting it so that I could send data from the phone to the arduino. I noticed in the CurieBle examples there was a project called "Callback LED" but when I connected to the Arduino from the Phone gap app I noticed in the debug message about characteristics it said `"properties":{"notify": true, "read": true}` but nothing about write. I tried writing "Hello world" (converted into bytes then encoded string) I got an error similar to (I couldn't copy it exactly as it was an alert on the phone): `"error": "write", "message": "Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code = 3 \"Writing is not permitted.\" ..."...`There is more detail to the error message that is not at all relevant and is slightly repetitive.
Here is the arduino code (which is almost straight from the example):

```
#include <CurieBle.h>

const int ledPin = 13; // set ledPin to use on-board LED
BLEPeripheral blePeripheral; // create peripheral instance

BLEService ledService("19B10000-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214"); // create service

// create switch characteristic and allow remote device to read and write
BLECharCharacteristic switchChar("19B10001-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // use the LED on pin 13 as an output
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  while(!Serial);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  // set the local name peripheral advertises
  blePeripheral.setLocalName("LEDCB");
  // set the UUID for the service this peripheral advertises
  blePeripheral.setAdvertisedServiceUuid(ledService.uuid());

  // add service and characteristic
  blePeripheral.addAttribute(ledService);
  blePeripheral.addAttribute(switchChar);

  // assign event handlers for connected, disconnected to peripheral
  blePeripheral.setEventHandler(BLEConnected, blePeripheralConnectHandler);
  blePeripheral.setEventHandler(BLEDisconnected, blePeripheralDisconnectHandler);

  // assign event handlers for characteristic
  switchChar.setEventHandler(BLEWritten, switchCharacteristicWritten);
// set an initial value for the characteristic
  switchChar.setValue(0);

  // advertise the service
  blePeripheral.begin();
  Serial.println(("Bluetooth device active, waiting for connections..."));
}

void loop() {
  // poll peripheral
  blePeripheral.poll();
}

void blePeripheralConnectHandler(BLECentral& central) {
  // central connected event handler
  Serial.print("Connected event, central: ");
  Serial.println(central.address());
}

void blePeripheralDisconnectHandler(BLECentral& central) {
  // central disconnected event handler
  Serial.print("Disconnected event, central: ");
  Serial.println(central.address());
}

void switchCharacteristicWritten(BLECentral& central, BLECharacteristic& characteristic) {
  // central wrote new value to characteristic, update LED
  Serial.print("Characteristic event, written: ");

  if (switchChar.value()) {
    Serial.println("LED on");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  } else {
    Serial.println("LED off");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

Here is the write function (phonegap) which is where the error is being produced from :

```
var string = "Hello World";
var bytes = bluetoothle.stringToBytes(string);
var encodedString = _arrayBufferToBase64(bytes);
alert("Service : " + connection.service + "  char : " + connection.char + " Address: " + address);
var params = {"value":encodedString,"service":connection.service,"characteristic":connection.char,"address":address};
alert("params : " + JSON.stringify(params));
bluetoothle.write(function(res) {
alert("Success writing : " + JSON.stringify(res));
}, function(err) {
alert("Error writing: " + JSON.stringify(err));
}, params);
```

I think the error lies in the fact that the Arduino appears not to be advertising the "write" characteristic.
BTW the phone tells me that the service was `180d` and the characteristic was `2a37`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out thanks to finding [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/01org/corelibs-arduino101/issues/96). It turns out to be an error with CurieBLE which manifests in a way that means that on IOS it reads the original characteristics and services so when I tried to write it was still thought that the characteristic was `read-only`. I had to restart my phone and it is working now.
There was another thing which is that I needed to send a shorter message, I think it was 20 bytes max per message although I'm not sure, but I sent "h" and the Arduino received it.

Comment: I can't for another two days :-( but I will...

Comment: Yes, iOS seems to cache a lot of things by peripheral hardware address and not notice that they have changed for quite some time.  If you change addresses it will think you are something new, or else you have to get iOS to flush its cache.